How to get specific files within a folder from google drive API in node js. I have Folder id and some file ids
How to get specific files within a folder in node js. I have Folder id and some file ids.
const response = await drive.files.list({
    q: `'${folderId}' in parents and '${fileId}' in parents`
});

this not return a anything. and i need to send multiple file ids

About '${fileId}' in parents, is this '${folderId}' in parents? If my understanding is correct, In your search query, I think that it is required to use or. So, how about modifying from '${folderId}' in parents and '${fileId}' in parents to '${folderId1}' in parents or '${folderId2}' in parents? If you don't want to include the files of the trash box, please modify to ('${folderId1}' in parents or '${folderId2}' in parents) and trashed = false

@Tanaike I have folder in google drive i need to only specific files. in the application i'll send some fileId s. In result I want other files excluding that providing files.

Thank you for replying. About I have folder in google drive i need to only specific files., in your situation, you want to retrieve the file metadata of the specific file ID you have already known. Is my understanding correct?

@Tanaike i need file meta data like fileId.can you modify this query.
const response = await drive.files.list({
q: '${folderId}' in parents and trashed=false 
})

Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot understand the answer to my question in your situation, you want to retrieve the file metadata of the specific file ID you have already known. Is my understanding correct?. And, what is i need file meta data like fileId?

@Tanaike yes. im sending folder id and file id.

Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from yes. im sending folder id and file id., I couldn't understand about the answer to my question in your situation, you want to retrieve the file metadata of the specific file ID you have already known. Is my understanding correct? and i need file meta data like fileId. Can I ask you about the details of your goal?
